# How do I Use Unicode Strings in pubish/subscribe?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish and subscribe unicode strings (multibyte text).
but, If I did it then  UnicodeEncodeError was Occured.

Can I use multibyte text in publish and subscribe ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269873/how-do-i-use-unicode-strings-in-pubish/subscribe?/) by [NGI](https://answers.ros.org/users/31738/ngi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can I use multibyte text in publish and subscribe ?

I don't think that it is supported in ROS1. From [ros/wiki/msg - Fields](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields):

> unicode strings are currently not supported as a ROS data type. utf-8 should be used to be compatible with ROS string serialization. In python 2, this encoding is automatic for `unicode` objects, but decoding must be done manually. In python 3, when using `str`, both encoding and decoding using 'utf-8' in the generated message code.

One workaround I can think of is to instead of using the `string` type, using the `uint8` type. Serialise your wide-string yourself into that `uint8` array, publish it, and in the subscriber recreate the wide-string.

That is not nice (as you lose the type info), but could work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NGI](https://answers.ros.org/users/31738/ngi/) on 2017-08-30**:
Thank you for your answer.

I understood it.

For a while, I'll try it.

**Comment by [NGI](https://answers.ros.org/users/31738/ngi/) on 2017-08-30**:
I checked it.Thanks!

And, I found other way.
I can recieve Unicode Message by above sequence.

in Publish Node: Original text [unicode] => text.encode('utf-8') [change to str] => publish
in Subscribe Node: subscribe => text=data.data [str] => text.decode('utf-8') [unicode]

Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-30**:
If that works, then you should post it as an answer instead of a comment.